# I can’t get the user id

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I was writing a bot and I was dealing with this problem.
Who knows how to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sZqv.png)

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import message
from aiogram.utils import executor

import os


bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#clien
@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start', 'help'])
async def commands_start(massage : types.message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hello, who are you?")





executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: You must include a [mre], and you have to include everything _as text_ in your post, not in screenshots. Please see the [tour], the [ask] page, and the [help/on-topic] for more info on why.

Comment: where is your code, this tells us absolutely nothing other than `user_id` attribute is not found

Comment: @RyanMillares i fixed

Comment: @RandomDavis fixed

Comment: @ins1deins1dovich FYI you still do not have a full stacktrace of the error, and the error you do have is still an image. That's not helpful to any users who might be searching for a solution to that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async def commands_start(massage : types.message):` seems to use "massage" instead of "message", try fixing that and see if it works

Comment: @ins1deins1dovich does it work now or still errors?